# SDL Keyboard and mouse events for navigation with modern OpenGL

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl

I have some troubles implementing some events in SDL with modern OpenGL. Can you guys please help me?

I have followed [thebennybox's tutorials](http://youtu.be/ftiKrP3gW3k?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh) until episode 3.5. Also I'm now trying to implement [this guy's](http://youtu.be/f-vxvZGI8R0?list=PL0AB023E769342AFE) keyboard and mouse navigation on the code I have from thebennybox.

I use a MacBook Air 13'.

So far I have this code in main.cpp:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Display.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Camera.h"

int main(){
Camera camera;

Uint32 start;
SDL_Event event;
//glew 1.50 which glGenVertexArrays doesnt work without the 
//glewExperimental flag. so it is glew version dependent
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

//Create Window with SDL
Display display(800, 600, "OpenGL Terrain");

//Create the vertices we want to draw
Vertex vertices[] = {   Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.5,-0.5,0)),
                        Vertex(glm::vec3(0,0.5,0)),
                        Vertex(glm::vec3(0.5,-0.5,0))};

//Send the vertices to GPU with mesh function
Mesh mesh(vertices, sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0]) );

//Create vertex and fragment shaders
Shader shader("../shaders/shader");

//render 
while(!display.IsClosed()){
    //Clear the window
    display.Clear(0.0f,0.15f,0.23f,1.0f);

    //Bind the shaders
    shader.Bind();
    
    //Draw the vertices
    mesh.Draw();
    
    //Show it all
    display.Update();
    
    //Call to functions of the Camera Class
    camera.Control(0.2,0.2,false);
    camera.updateCamera();
}

return 0;
}
```

This in Camera.cpp:

```
 #include "Camera.h"


 bool Camera::mouseInsideOfWindow = false;

 Camera::Camera() {

    Camera::cameraPositionX = 0.0f;
    Camera::cameraPositionY = 0.0f;
    Camera::cameraPositionZ = 5.0f;
    Camera::cameraPitch = 0.0f;
    Camera::cameraYaw = 0.0f;


 }
void Camera::lockCamera(){
    //Put some restriction for the view 
    if(cameraPitch > 90.0f){cameraPitch = 90.0f;}
    if(cameraPitch < -90.0f){cameraPitch = -90.0f;}
    if(cameraYaw < 0.0f){cameraYaw += 360.0f;}
    if(cameraYaw > 360.0f){cameraYaw -= 360.0f;}
}
void Camera::moveCamera(float distance, float direction){
    //convert the radius to angles
    float rad = (cameraYaw+direction)*M_PI/180.0f;
    cameraPositionX -= sin(rad)*distance;
    cameraPositionZ -= cos(rad)*distance;
}
    void Camera::moveCameraUp(float distance, float direction){
    float rad = (cameraPitch+direction)*M_PI/180.0f;
    cameraPositionY += sin(rad)*distance;
}
void Camera::Control(float moveVelocity,float mouseVelocity,bool mouseInsideWindow){

    //if the mouse is inside the window
    if(mouseInsideWindow){
    //std::cout << "Innan " << std::endl;
    int centerWindowX = 400;
    int centerWindowY = 300;
    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE); // dont show the mouse curser
    int tempX, tempY;
    
    SDL_GetMouseState(&tempX,&tempY); // get the points where the mouse is
    cameraYaw   += mouseVelocity*(centerWindowX-tempX); // calculate yaw
    cameraPitch += mouseVelocity*(centerWindowY-tempY); // calculate pitch
    lockCamera(); // lock the view 
    // Put back the curser in center
    SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(NULL,centerWindowX,centerWindowY);
    
    const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    //Move the Camera
    if(state[SDLK_w]){
        std::cout << "W" << std::endl;
        if(cameraPitch != 90 && cameraPitch != -90){
            moveCamera(moveVelocity,0.0);
            moveCameraUp(moveVelocity,0.0);
        }
    }
    else if(state[SDLK_s]){
        std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
        if(cameraPitch != 90 && cameraPitch != -90){
            moveCamera(moveVelocity,180.0);
            moveCameraUp(moveVelocity,180.0);
        }            
    }
    if(state[SDLK_a]){
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        moveCamera(moveVelocity,90.0);
    }
    else if (state[SDLK_d]){
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
        moveCamera(moveVelocity,270.0);
    }
    
    //Close the window

}
//Rotate the Camera
    glRotatef(-cameraPitch,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(-cameraYaw,0.0,1.0,0.0);

}
void Camera::updateCamera(){
    glTranslatef(-cameraPositionX,-cameraPositionY,cameraPositionZ);
}
Camera::~Camera() {}
```

So I'm not sure what I'm missing. I have a feeling that it is something to do with `SDL_Event`? What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Basically what I want is to be able to move with (w,s,a,d) and use the mouse for direction.

Do I need to add the rest of the code? Please can someone help me?

Have I made myself understood? Otherwise please ask.

p.s. The simple triangle example in a window works fine, but not the navigation.

/K

Comment: Where are you polling for events?

Comment: Thats what the problem is, it think. I don't know where or how to do it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

In SDL you generally poll for events so your application can react to input like mouse or keyboard actions.

Currently you render in your main loop:

```
//render 
while(!display.IsClosed()){
    // draw stuff
}
```

You need to poll for events in this loop too:

```
SDL_Event e;
if( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) { 
    // handle your event here
}
```

The author youtube page you linked to has videos on this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzZa_pg9_-A

You can also take a look at the lazyfoo tutorials which are a popular way of learning SDL:
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php

Answer (score -1):

I added the `SDL_Event` to the `display.update()` function in the `Display` class like this:

```
void Display::Update() {
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Event event;
    
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        switch(event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                m_isClosed = true;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseInsideOfWindow = true;
                SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q){
                    mouseInsideOfWindow = false;
                    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_ENABLE);
                    break;
                }
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
                    m_isClosed = true;
                    break;
                }
                 
            
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w){
                
                    //Do I do something here? look at Camera::control() function!!!
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Display::Update` function is called in the while loop in main.cpp. It works fine with the mouse click and ESCAPE but (w,a,s,d) does not work. I'm using SDL2 and in this update I can not find `SDL_GetKeyState` (look at `Camera::control`) but instead there is a function called

```
const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
```

And I think the problem is in there. How do I fix it so the w,a,s,d keys work as well?